# ReactiveMongo with SSL

Tags: mongodb, scala, ssl, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I am trying to set up a Play application that will connect to a mongoDB using the ReactiveMongo Scala driver.  I have gotten it working but would ultimately like to connect to a mongoDB that has been built with SSL support.  Does ReactiveMongo provide the ability to connect to a mongoDB over SSL?

I have been able to connect over SSL with Casbah in the past using

```
MongoClient(List[ServerAddress], 
            MongoClientOptions(socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault))
```

I would like to use ReactiveMongo due to the asynchronous non-blocking nature, but I could use Casbah if that is my only option.

Comment: I looked at the code and haven't found anything that would suggest ssl support. You can ask for help in ReactiveMongo user group, though: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/reactivemongo Also you can file feature request here https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/issues?state=open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reactive Mongo is built on Netty, adding SSL support shouldn't be much more than a line of code to insert the SSL handler into the Netty pipeline plus a few lines for making it configurable, I'd suggest making a pull request.